Duplicate mock definition error when using @MockBean to override bean in multiple Spring Boot test classes
I have multiple Spring Boot tests where I need to override a bean that is loaded in the test context using the @SpringBootTest annotation. In one of my test classes, I successfully used the @MockBean annotation to override a bean called AwsFireLogger defined in the thConfiguration.class. However, when I added the @MockBean annotation in another test class that also uses the same configuration class, I encountered an error stating "Duplicate mock definition". How can I resolve this issue and successfully override the bean in both test classes?
Here is an example of the code structure:
@SpringBootTest(classes = { thConfiguration.class, CaffeineCacheConfiguration.class })
public class FirstTestClass {
    @MockBean
    private AwsFireLogger awsFireLogger;

    // Rest of the test code...
}

@SpringBootTest(classes = { thConfiguration.class, CaffeineCacheConfiguration.class })
public class SecondTestClass {
    @MockBean
    private AwsFireLogger awsFireLogger;

    // Rest of the test code...
}

When I run the tests, the first test class runs successfully, but the second test class throws an exception with the message "Duplicate mock definition". How can I resolve this issue and ensure that both test classes can override the AwsFireLogger bean?
I tried also doing something like:
public class BaseIntegrationTest {

    @MockBean
    AwsFireLogger awsFireLogger ;
}

And then extend from my test classes but at some point the bean wasn't injected in the context and I got errors related with that.
Thanks in advance!

Specify unique names for each @MockBean:
@SpringBootTest(classes = { thConfiguration.class, CaffeineCacheConfiguration.class })
public class FirstTestClass {
    @MockBean(name = "firstAwsFireLogger")
    private AwsFireLogger awsFireLogger;

    // Rest of the test code...
}

@SpringBootTest(classes = { thConfiguration.class, CaffeineCacheConfiguration.class })
public class SecondTestClass {
    @MockBean(name = "secondAwsFireLogger")
    private AwsFireLogger awsFireLogger;

    // Rest of the test code...
}


It seems like it is working, but I had to name just the second one, for some reason if I name both I got the same error

Strange, are you sure the names are different from each other? @rasilvap

Change the name of the instance field containing @MockBean and try again to test.
Updated code:
@SpringBootTest(classes = { thConfiguration.class, CaffeineCacheConfiguration.class })
public class FirstTestClass {
    @MockBean
    private AwsFireLogger awsFireLoggerFirstTest;

    // Rest of the test code...
}

@SpringBootTest(classes = { thConfiguration.class, CaffeineCacheConfiguration.class })
public class SecondTestClass {
    @MockBean
    private AwsFireLogger awsFireLoggerSecondTest;

    // Rest of the test code...
}

See if this helps.

That didn't work for me
